# Get error when use Rcpp remove rows of matrix

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat fed(arma::mat x){
arma::mat zz=x.shed_rows(0,2);
return(zz);
}
```

Just want remove some rows from matrix, get error as follows.
conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'arma::Mat} requested'

Comment: Please do not post screen shots.  There is never a good reason to do so, and you could have copied the text more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two points:

- Please don't post error messages as image. Use Text instead.
- As the error indicates, the `shed_rows()` method does not return anything. Instead it alters the matrix it acts on, c.f. [the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#shed).

The following works:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat fed(arma::mat x){
    x.shed_rows(0,2);
    return(x);
}

/*** R
fed(matrix(1:16, 4 ,4))
*/
```